# How do you take a function from an excel spreadsheet and run it with python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

Hello whoever is reading this.
I am having trouble taking a python function from an excel spreadsheet and then running it in python.
I'd like to stress on the fact that I actually defined my function in python, and it's not an excel function.

Please note that this is my second time questioning and have only ever done coding as a hobby.

Here is an example of what I want to take:
[heal(2,c)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zc5c.png)

I am using xlrd to analyze data on the spreadsheet.
Here is a chunk from my code.

```
    e = worksheet.cell(rowidx,colidx+1)
    f = str(e).replace("'","")
    g = f.replace("text:","")
```

This chunk focuses on converting the 'cell object' to a 'string' and making it look like the function required.
The end result is this:

```
    g = heal(2,c)
```

My problem is that I cannot seem to activate this function.
I have also tried doing "g()" but it came up with the error message:
*File "C:\Users\Alexander\Dropbox\Documents\Python\Hearthstone\Hearthstone.py", line 18, in play
    g()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable*

I do not mind if you tell me a way to activate "g" or just directly run it from the spreadsheet.
Please let me know if you need any more information.
Thank you for you time.

Comment: heal() function is in current file or from function is defined in some other file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) for same. Here, I am considering that funciton is defined in current file only.

Example:

```
eval('heal(2,c)')
```

If function is defined in other file i.e. "file",import it and call using:

Example:
import file

```
eval('file.heal(2,c)')
```

Comment: Thankyou! The eval function seems to suit its purpose.